# Why Datatables return Null when it is executed via SQL Command text?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I got two classes, one for db connection and another to get data. When I use the `SqlCommand` type as stored procedure it returns the data table properly, but when I change the command type to text and change the command text properly it returns a null value. Why is this happening?

Class 1

```
public class DB_Connection
{
    public SqlConnection cnn;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    public SqlDataAdapter ada;

    public DB_Connection()
    {
        cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=svr01;Initial Catalog=PDFScramble;Integrated Security=True");
        cnn.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;// *changed in here SP or Text*
        cmd.Connection = cnn;

        ada = new SqlDataAdapter();
        ada.SelectCommand = cmd;            
    }
```

Class 2

```
public class Data : DB_Connection
{
    public string DException { get; set; }
    public DataTable Datatable { get; set; }

    public bool GetCivicEntities()
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Description, StateId ,EntityTypeId FROM CivicEntities";
            ada.Fill(Datatable);// *Null in here*
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DException = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Who initializes `Data.Datatable`  property?

Comment: Did you **create** (instantiate) the `Datatable` before calling `GetCivicEntities()` ?? The method itself never instantiates that data table - so it has be instantiated before calling the method.....

Comment: Check my solution and tell me if helped.

Comment: @Sundar Singh > Im not trying to use a SP here.

Comment: you have not initialized Datatable.

Comment: Yap, that was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Datatable is null, because of that you have this problem. This should fix it.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Description, StateId ,EntityTypeId FROM CivicEntities";
 Datatable = new DataTable();
 ada.Fill(Datatable);
 return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the class structure. Check with this

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlParameter prm = null;
SqlDataAdapter dad = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

cmd = new SqlCommand("SPName", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

conn.Open();
dad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


dad.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();
}


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlParameter prm = null;
SqlDataAdapter dad = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dummy",conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
conn.Open();
dad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


dad.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Its working, but still i get the problem with my code. its the same thing and it works when i call trough the stored procedure.

Comment: How this answers the question? Your code sample significantly differs from OP. Besides, what's the point in declaring all variables before they will be used?